# Undefined index in array (PHP)

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Intento eliminar un dato de una tabla con un botón, pero no me define la `id` y no se la razón:

```
<?php
    require_once 'conexion.php' ;

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $id = $_POST['id'];
        //ejecutar la conexion
        $Eliminar = $pdo->prepare('DELETE FROM programar_descarga WHERE id= ?');
        $Eliminar->execute(array($id));   
        print_r($Eliminar->errorInfo());
    }
?>
```

> error: Notice: Undefined index: id in
> /var/www/html/dsi/grupo31/web/delete_eliminar.php on line 5 Array (
> [0] => 00000 [1] => [2] => )

Comment: Cómo tienes el nombre del input en tu html?

Comment: deberia ser `isset($_POST['id'])`

Comment: Añade después del require un print_r($_POST); a ver si te dice que llega el id. En este caso es importante que indiques cómo se está haciendo la petición. Si es un formulario web indica el código para que lo echemos un vistazo ok?

Comment: Hay varios detalles: 1. ¿Hay en el formulario algún elemento `<input name="id" type="algún_tipo_válido" value="el_id_que_te_interesa">` si no lo hay no cuentas con el `id` 2. Como usas marcador posicional `?` en tu sentencia preparada debes hacer `bindParam(tipo, valor)` para ligar el id y no lo haces. tipo debe ser una cadena con la letra identificadora del tipo. 3. si deseas usar arrays de parámetros el query debe cambiar a `WHERE id= :id` y el array en execute `array(':id' => $id)` con estos ajustes te funciona. Si usas 3 no necesitas hacer bindParam